# Calculate average duration between two dates in a pivot table calculated field

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, moving-average

I want to calculate in a pivot table the average duration between two changes (dates) for each item.

Here is the sheet that contains datas:

| Item | Changed on |
| --- | --- |
| item3 | 2023-01-25 |
| item2 | 2022-10-12 |
| item3 | 2022-08-15 |
| item3 | 2022-03-06 |
| item2 | 2021-12-18 |
| item1 | 2021-06-28 |

I need a pivot table to calculate the average duration of each item, like this:

| Item | Avg. time between two changes |
| --- | --- |
| item1 | no data |
| item2 | 298 |
| item3 | 162.5 |

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: do dates always descend? also are you looking for avg for every item individually or all of them?

Comment: @player0, dates not always descend.
I added an example of expected pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(a, b, QUERY(QUERY({a, IFNA(VLOOKUP(a&"×"&
 COUNTIFS(a, a, ROW(a), "<="&ROW(a))-1, {a&"×"&
 COUNTIFS(a, a, ROW(a), "<="&ROW(a)), b}, 2, )-b)}, 
 "select Col1,avg(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1"), 
 "offset 1", ))(A:A, B:B))
```

[image]

---

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(a, b, {SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(a, a<>""))), 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(a, a<>""))), 
 QUERY(QUERY({a, IFNA(VLOOKUP(a&"×"&
 COUNTIFS(a, a, ROW(a), "<="&ROW(a))-1, {a&"×"&
 COUNTIFS(a, a, ROW(a), "<="&ROW(a)), b}, 2, )-b)}, 
 "select Col1,avg(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1"), 
 "offset 1", ), 2, ), "no data")})(A:A, B:B))
```

[image]

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(a; b; {SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(a; a<>"")))\ 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(a; a<>""))); 
 QUERY(QUERY({a\ IFNA(VLOOKUP(a&"×"&
 COUNTIFS(a; a; ROW(a); "<="&ROW(a))-1; {a&"×"&
 COUNTIFS(a; a; ROW(a); "<="&ROW(a))\ b}; 2; )-b)}; 
 "select Col1,avg(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1"); 
 "offset 1"; ); 2; ); "no data")})(A:A; B:B))
```

Comment: It's a fail. Cells display #ERROR!

Are you sure for aliases Col1 and Col2 ?

Comment: @JoëlRoyer try 3rd formula

Comment: #ERROR! replaced by item name. Google Sheet does not allow me to enter a formula on several lines in pivot table calculated field. It puts everything on one line.

Comment: @JoëlRoyer this solution is not for calculated field within the pivot table. just a formula you enter in any cell